# linux - Find OS disk size using df and awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
size=`df / | awk '{print $4}'`
```

The following code works, however it also prints the word 'Available':

```
Available
2079328628
```

How can I take only the size into `size` variable?

Comment: `size=\`df / | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1\``

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the first line:

```sh
size=$(df / | awk 'NR>1{print $4}')
```

Here, `NR>1` only prints the fourth field value if the line is not the first one.

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/qcTxo3).

Comment: `read -r -d '' _ avail < <(df --output=avail /)`

Comment: `read -d '' _ avail < <(df --output=avail /)`

Comment: I know what `-r` means. There are no backslashes in the input, there is nothing to mangle here. `-r` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

Using `--output` option in `gnu df` you can pick & chose fields that you want in output. So you can use:

```sh
df --output=avail / | sed '1d'
```

OR:

```sh
df --output=avail / | tail -n +2
```

OR:

```sh
df --output=avail / | awk 'NR>1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using just one sub-shell for `df` and parsing with Bash built-in features:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -d '' _ avail < <(df --output=avail /)
```

No sub-shell at all version:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

trap 'rm -f "$tmpfile"' EXIT
tmpfile="/tmp/avail_$RANDOM"
df --output=avail / >"$tmpfile"
read -r -d '' _ avail <"$tmpfile"
echo "$avail"
```

Answer (score 0):

Two more using `df` and `awk`:

```
df | awk '{if ($4 != "Available") print $4}'
```

and

```
df | grep -v Available| awk '{print $4}'
```